# Reference of R. Kloosterman

Tags: reference-request, tate-shafarevich-groups

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59218/which-primes-can-divide-orders-of-tate-shafarevich-groups), Clark suggests to use the theorem of R. Kloosterman, and then mentions one of [his papers](http://www.numdam.org/article/JTNB_2005__17_3_787_0.pdf). I searched this theorem in his paper but I didn't find anything close to this theorem. Where can I find the proof of this theorem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it just a direct consequence of Theorem 1.1 there?

Comment: Can’t believe I missed it. Thank you.